# Adding new line between objects and comments in Prettier or ESLint

Tags: formatting, eslint, formatter, prettier

I use VS Code with Prettier and ESLint installed. I wonder whether I can have rules like these:

1. Adding a new line between end of a code block and a comment(in all types of files - html, css, js etc):

> ```
>         //comment something
>         function make() {
>           doSomething();
>         }
>         //formatter adds this line to separate the bracket above from the comment below
>         //comment something
>         function make() {
>           doSomething();
>         }
> ```

2. Similar rule for objects and nested objects without comments:

> ```
> const obj = {
>
>     prop: {
>     foo: 'bar'
>     },
>
>     prop2: {
>     foo: 'bar'
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own ESLint rule for this

Comment: I actually learnt that prettier doesn't allow it.